# how to log POST data in the apache access.log?

Tags: apache

I want to log the POST data in Apache's `access.log` file.

Other questions on SOF have mentioned use of `mod_dumpio` and `mod_dumpost`, but they log the POST data in `error.log` not the `access.log` file.

How can I log the POST data in `access.log`?

Comment: Strange... Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score -1):

You can't, unless you want to write a new Apache module that puts the entire POST body into an environment variable that can then be logged.